# using xr with import package

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I am working on the following project.  It is a series of labs designed to teach numerical computing.
https://github.com/byuimpact/numerical_computing

The latex files are organized into to subdirectories which are subimported into `Vol1.tex` in the main root directory.

Problem: I want to reference entire labs from within other labs.  So if I am in lab1, be able to refer to 'lab 2' with a hyperlink to lab2.  How can this be done.
At the beginning of some labs, I have `\label{lab:lab1}`, but trying to refer to it with `\ref{lab:lab1}` in `lab2.tex` does not seem to work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: if you import (or input) the files to make one large master file with one pdf you don't want `xr` the fact that the source is split over many files should make no difference. `xr` is for referencing from one document to another. Perhaps you could make a minimal example with a couple of 2 line files that shows the problem.

Comment: Without a proper MWE, we can't really see why `xr` is needed, so this is 'unclear' I'm afraid.